# Do I "Recommend Deletion" to old answers on closed questions about off-site resource recommendation?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, link-only-answers

I skipped a bunch of these posts in the LQP queue, though.

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/18259859
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/18259947
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/18260687
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/18259813
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/18260715

... and a lot more.

If it were an answer to a regular question, I would have picked "RD". However, these answers are a bit different:

- They've been around for quite a while.
- The questions are bad. In fact in 90%+ cases, the Qs are already closed, with the correct close reason.
- I am not experienced enough in the specific subjects to judge whether the recommendations are appropriate or helpful, but I am fairly sure they aren't good answers on Stack Óverflòw.
- A lot of them have a positive score.

What's your opinions on handling these answers?

Comment: Óverflòw... Got a lîttlė õvérzèªlòūs wïth thôsę âćčéńts?

Comment: @DavyM A̦̺̪̠̞̾̅ͣ̀t͕̼̮͙́ͪ̉̌̑ͦ̕ ̦̈́̈́͠l̺͔̻̠̺̼̓ͤͯ͆ͮͮe͓̙͇̐a͗̒̔͌̔̂͏ͅś͈̝ͦ̓̑ͨ̀͢tͤ̚ ̺̦̫͓̻͛n͂ͯͫ̒o̠̠̺̗̺̲̓ͥͣͬͤͅt̢̩͓͎̱͈͎̍ ͔̝̈́̊ͩ́̆ͮz̬̦̃̊ͨ̅͗͆ͦả͉͙͉͍͍͛̽ͦl̵̖g͚͓̎̉o̝̱ͯ̊ ̣̪͇̩͗t̲̪̤̜̬̰͔ͮͯͬe̋̀̓̑̕x͓̺̜̀t͓͕̜͙̦̫̓ͨ̍̆̃͢.

Comment: [*when the question is kinda asking for bad answers this is to be expected. Close or flag the question and move on - this is much more efficient than hanging around to babysit it by deleting every crap answer that inevitably shows up.*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Comment: Also, I really don't know why people are flagging those as NAAs. ALL those posts were closed, was a flag even required? Delete the question instead. :|

Comment: @BhargavRao They have a lot of upvotes.

Comment: @iBug you can delete questions even if they've got upvotes. It's just that you need more voters.

Comment: @BhargavRao But I'm faced with ***answers*** under them.

Comment: Exactly, the issue is actually with those who put them into the queue. It shouldn't have been there. In these cases, recommending deletion won't actually help. As the answers are upvoted, they can't be deleted in the LQPQ, so they'll be sent to the moderator queue.

Comment: @BhargavRao Do/Should I flag those Qs for mod?

Comment: What exactly do you want to flag for mod? Don't flag those answers now, because the moderators will already get an automatic flag for them. (nearly 400 of those in the queue already).

Comment: @BhargavRao I meant exaclty, flagging the questions for Mod.

Comment: I am still not sure, why do you even need to flag the already closed questions for moderator attention? The community users (20k+) can handle these easily.

Comment: @BhargavRao Thanks. I got it.